# Wordpress .htaccess file on root creating issues for sub directories

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this very critical issue of Wordpress messing up with my website's sub directories. Following is the very detailed info.

1. I have a wordpress installed on root . Unfortunately, I cannot move it to a folder.
2. I have 3 other custom PHP applications in following 3 respective directories

   a. /client

   b. /console

   c. /order

Following are the .htaccess code for each of these directories

**.htaccess code for /client folder**

```
# This Directive will make Apache look first  
# for "index_good.html" before looking for "index.html"  

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^orders$ orders.php
RewriteRule ^profile$ profile.php
RewriteRule ^orders/pending$ orders.php?type=pending
RewriteRule ^orders/completed$ orders.php?type=completed
RewriteRule ^logincheck$ logincheck.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
RewriteRule ^ticket/open$ support-ticket-open.php
RewriteRule ^ticket/open/step/2$ support-ticket-open-2.php



RewriteRule ^order/view/(\w+)$ show-order-details.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess for /console** folder

```
# This Directive will make Apache look first  
# for "index_good.html" before looking for "index.html"  

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^orders$ orders.php
RewriteRule ^services$ services.php
RewriteRule ^service/add$ add-service.php
RewriteRule ^coupons$ coupons.php
RewriteRule ^markups$ markups.php
RewriteRule ^markups/view/maincat$ markups.php?view=maincat
RewriteRule ^markups/view/markup$ markups.php?view=markup
RewriteRule ^markups/view/option$ markups.php?view=option
RewriteRule ^order/add/step/(\w+)$ add-order.php?step=$1
RewriteRule ^order/add$ add-order.php
RewriteRule ^client/add$ add-client.php
RewriteRule ^clients$ clients.php
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
RewriteRule ^ordering/service$ service-ordering.php
RewriteRule ^ordering/markup$ markup-ordering.php
RewriteRule ^setting/markup$ markup-setting.php
RewriteRule ^setting/general$ general-settings.php
RewriteRule ^tickets$ tickets.php
RewriteRule ^ticket/open$ open-ticket.php




RewriteRule ^order/view/(\w+)$ show-order-details.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^client/orders/(\w+)$ orders.php?client_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ticket/update/([\w-]+)$ update-ticket.php?ticket_no=$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess for order folder**

```
# This Directive will make Apache look first  
# for "index_good.html" before looking for "index.html"  

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^order$ order.php
RewriteRule ^order/([^/\.]+)/$ order.php?service=$1
RewriteRule ^order/view/(\w+)$ show-order-details.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess for Wordpress**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now the issue is that all /client & /console folder are properly accessible. But I have a folder called /server/php/ inside /order folder. This folder seems to be inaccessible and redirects to a Wordpress 404 page. I've been trying hard. But, everything is in vain. Please lemme know what the issue can be . Also, I cannot move the Wordpress to a /wp folder. So, please advice accordingly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had an issue like this, i had a cakephp app in a subdirectory that has wordpress ass root, edit your wordpress htaccess to look like this

```
#Action php /cgi-php52/php
#AddHandler php52 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(order/server/php/|order/server/php/.*)$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is basically telling it to ignore Rewrite condition for the url that point to folders client, console and order

Comment: Its actually a wordpress page for page not found  YOU can check it out in the title tag.

Comment: :- Issue Resolved. Copied your .htaccess code. Also, the directory permissions for /php folder was set to 0750 instead of 0755. So,  just changed it and its working perfect. Thanks for your hep. Really appreciated